# Add two PostgreSQL connector type with different configs in Trino config file

Tags: postgresql, presto, trino, presto-jdbc

I have two databases within my PostgreSQL instance and I'm looking to connect them to Trino. I've added their configurations to the postgres.properties file located in the catalog folder:

```
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
connection-user=postgres
connection-password=postgres
case-insensitive-name-matching= true



connector.name=postgresql
connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/report
connection-user=postgres
connection-password=postgres
case-insensitive-name-matching= true
```

But I just can see one of them in Trino.